# JQuery - Ajax call completes after next line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax function which dynamically adds options to a dropdown list.

```
var getData = function() {

    $.getJSON('api/someurl')
            .done(function (data) {

                console.log(data);


                var results = $("#Mydropdown")
                              .empty()
                              .append("<option value=''>Please select</option>");

               // loop data and build list
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {

            });
};
```

If I already have a value selected which I hold in some input field, then on page load I want to recreate the list and set the selected option to what was previously selected.

The following doesn't work. In the console I can see the ajax data is being returned after this line executes `$('#Mydropdown').val($("#SelectedVal").val());` so the value isn't getting selected?

```
if ($("#SelectedVal").val()) {
    getData(); // this function logs to console too
    $('#Mydropdown').val($("#SelectedVal").val());
    console.log('done');
}
```

How do I fix?

*** Note ***
I call the getData function in other functions as well which is why I don't pass the selected value in the above scenario in the function.

Comment: It's an asynchronous request. It will complete after the rest of your SYNCHRONOUS code has completed. In other words, your code doesn't stop and wait for the request to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the selected value after updating the dropdown inside the success callback:

```
var selectedValue = $("#SelectedVal").val();
if (selectedValue) {
    getData(selectedValue);
}
```

and then:

```
var getData = function(selectedValue) {
    $.getJSON('api/someurl').done(function (data) {
        var results = $("#Mydropdown")
            .empty()
            .append("<option value=''>Please select</option>");

        // loop data and build list

        // after you have built the new list set the selected value
        // to what it previously was
        $('#Mydropdown').val(selectedValue);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    });
};
```

Alternatively if you don't want to set the selected value inside the `getData` function, you could use a callback:

```
var selectedValue = $("#SelectedVal").val();
if (selectedValue) {
    getData(function() {
        $("#SelectedVal").val(selectedValue);
    });
}
```

and your `getData` function might look like this:

```
var getData = function(callback) {
    $.getJSON('api/someurl').done(function (data) {
        var results = $("#Mydropdown")
            .empty()
            .append("<option value=''>Please select</option>");

        // loop data and build list

        // after you have built the new list invoke the callback
        callback();
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    });
};
```

Comment: I have updated the code using a callback and it seems to work but now when I call the same function like this: `$('#btn-get-data').click(getData);` I get error: `TypeError: callback is not a function`? I'm not too familar with callbacks.

Comment: Call it like this: `$('#btn-get-data').click(function() { getData(function() { $("#SelectedVal").val(selectedValue); }) });`

Answer (score 0):

you should **select value** in the callback of getdata success here: see attached code here:

```
       $.getJSON('api/someurl')
        .done(function (data) {


            var results = $("#Mydropdown")
                          .empty()
                          .append("<option value=''>Please select</option>");

           // loop data and build list
           //After List Build is Completed Select Drop Down Here

            $('#Mydropdown').val($("#SelectedVal").val());

            console.log('done');

        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use doneCallback function for example;

**Use callback**

```
var getData = function(doneCallback) {

    $.getJSON('api/someurl')
            .done(function (data) {

                console.log(data);


                var results = $("#Mydropdown")
                              .empty()
                              .append("<option value=''>Please select</option>");

               // loop data and build list
               if(doneCallback)
                doneCallback();
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {

            });
};
```

**Define callback**

```
if ($("#SelectedVal").val()) {
    getData(function(){
        $('#Mydropdown').val($("#SelectedVal").val());
    });
    console.log('done');
}
```